# Using variable in filebeat sources path

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat

I have log files separated into a directory structure by year, month , and day of month and I need to tell filebeat to ingest the log files for current month only.

How can I put the curent month variable in filebeat config file [ sources section paths ] so that filebeat ingest log files that belong to current month only. For now they are hard coded paths with filename patterns.

Answer (score 0):

If the files have already been imported, filebeat won't try to re-import them.  If you're trying to ignore the initial importation of older files, you can [edit the registry file](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/migration-registry-file.html) manually.

You can also use the `[ignore_older][1]` parameter on your input, which would give you a rolling window.

Comment: what if the files on file system are newly copied but the actual data belong to older months , i need to restrict the data provider to provide the current month data only in the current month , and i want to stop looking at older months even if the data has been copied later to those

Comment: You can compute the age of the document in logstash and drop anything that's too old.